# jQuery UI Draggable/Droppable

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using jQuery UI to drag and drop a list of items and call Ajax to update DB.

It works perfectly till the item text length is less than 50 characters and fails if greater than this.

Is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation sending data with AJAX or others methods (at least with `POST` params length or `GET` params under 2k chars because of URL limitation with some browsers).

Your limitation must be in the database side. Check the fields length.